# разное поведение arm-none-eabi-as в зависимости от текущей дериктории

Tags: ассемблер, makefile, stm32

Дано:

1. скрипт для линкера

`loop.ld`

```
SECTIONS {
    flash 0x08000000 : {
        LONG(0x20000000 + 20K);
        LONG(loop | 1);
        . = 0x130;
        loop.o(code);
    }
}
```

2. исходник на ассемблере

`loop.s`

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.syntax unified
.thumb

.global loop

.section code

loop:
    add r0, r0, 1
    bl loop
```

3. Макеfile

```
BUILD_DIR   = ../build
OBJCOPY     = arm-none-eabi-objcopy
LINKER      = arm-none-eabi-ld
ASM         = arm-none-eabi-as

loop.bin: loop.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -j flash $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.bin

loop.elf: loop.ld loop.o
    $(LINKER) -T loop.ld -o $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf loop.o

loop.o: loop.s
    $(ASM) -o loop.o loop.s

clean:
    rm -f loop.o $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.bin
```

Если все три файла расположены на одном логическом уровне иерархии проекта (напр. в папке `src`), то никаких проблем нет, проект успешно собирается:

```
STM32/01_loop/src$ make
arm-none-eabi-as -o loop.o loop.s
arm-none-eabi-ld -T loop.ld -o ../build/loop.elf loop.o
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary -j flash ../build/loop.elf ../build/loop.bin
```

Однако, если вывести `Makefile` в корневую директорию проекта:

3.1 новый `Makefile`:

```
BUILD_DIR   = ./build
SRC_DIR     = ./src
OBJCOPY     = arm-none-eabi-objcopy
LINKER      = arm-none-eabi-ld
ASM         = arm-none-eabi-as

all: loop.bin

loop.bin: loop.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -j flash $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.bin

loop.elf: $(SRC_DIR)/loop.ld $(SRC_DIR)/loop.o
    $(LINKER) -T $(SRC_DIR)/loop.ld -o $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf $(SRC_DIR)/loop.o

loop.o: $(SRC_DIR)/loop.s
    $(ASM) -o $(SRC_DIR)/loop.o $(SRC_DIR)/loop.s

clean:
    rm -f $(SRC_DIR)/loop.o $(SRC_DIR)/loop.s $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.bin
```

то начинаются вот такие ошибки:

```
/STM32/01_loop$ make
as   -o src/loop.o src/loop.s
src/loop.s: Assembler messages:
src/loop.s:1: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cpu'
src/loop.s:2: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.syntax'
src/loop.s:3: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.thumb'
src/loop.s:10: Error: too many memory references for `add'
src/loop.s:11: Error: no such instruction: `bl loop'
make: *** [<builtin>: src/loop.o] Error 1
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то ассемблер считает, что ему на вход подают исходник, требующий препроцессорную обработку (т.е. файл с расширением `.S`). Однако тут у меня два вопроса:

1. почему он так считает? Ведь на вход подан файл с расширением `.s`;
2. почему изменение логического расположения в иерархии влияет на поведение ассемблера?

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Так ведь другой ассемблер зовется, `as` вместо `arm-none-eabi-as`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat точно... Спасибо за наблюдательность. А почему так происходит?

Comment: А, увидел. Потому что у вас нет рецепта для `$(SRC_DIR)/loop.o`, только для `loop.o`. Поэтому для первого make применяет какой-то свой встроенный рецепт. Можно поставить в начало мейкфайла `MAKEFLAGS += -r`, чтобы такой фигни не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

#### Makefile

```
BUILD_DIR   = ./build
SRC_DIR     = ./src
OBJCOPY     = arm-none-eabi-objcopy
LINKER      = arm-none-eabi-ld
ASM         = arm-none-eabi-as

all: loop.bin

loop.bin: loop.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -j flash $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.bin

loop.elf: $(SRC_DIR)/loop.ld loop.o
    $(LINKER) -T $(SRC_DIR)/loop.ld -o $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.o

loop.o: $(SRC_DIR)/loop.s
    $(ASM) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.o $(SRC_DIR)/loop.s

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.o $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.bin

.PHONY: all
```

Для наглядности: строка, подвергшаяся изменениям:

```
loop.elf: $(SRC_DIR)/loop.ld $(SRC_DIR)/loop.o
    $(LINKER) -T $(SRC_DIR)/loop.ld -o $(BUILD_DIR)/loop.elf $(SRC_DIR)/loop.o
```

Далее возникла проблема следующего характера:

```
$ make
arm-none-eabi-as -o ./build/loop.o ./src/loop.s
arm-none-eabi-ld -T ./src/loop.ld -o ./build/loop.elf ./build/loop.o
arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find loop.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:13: loop.elf] Error 1
```

После некоторых изысканий удалось выяснить, что скрипт линкера необходимо модифицировать следующим образом:

#### loop.ld

```
SECTIONS {
    flash 0x08000000 : {
        LONG(0x20000000 + 20K);
        LONG(loop | 1);
        . = 0x130;
        ./build/loop.o(text);
    }
}
```

p.s. эта сборка относится к замечательному курсу ["Осваиваем SMT32 снизу"](https://www.linux.org.ru/articles/development/17345778)